# Maven create bundle with project

Tags: java, maven

I have developed a project that consists of two separated tiers that comprise two independent deployments. When I compile these projects they are deployed to my Nexus repository as separate artifacts.

These projects might evolve differnetly, so project A might be on version 1.0.1 and project B might be on version 1.0.5.

However, even though they are totally different deployments, the whole picture consists of the two independent projects, so I want to create a "meta-project" that packs the current artifacts of both projects into a single ZIP file (for instance, current release for today of the "whole picture" is project A v1.0.5 and project B v1.3.2). Both projects are WEB projects and thus WAR files.

I am struggling with Maven and the assembly plugin as to how to create such assembly, but haven't figured it out yet how to retrieve war dependencies from the repository and pack them together.

Answer (score 0):

Node "dependencySets" can be used for add all dependencies to final bundle:
http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/advanced-descriptor-topics.html

Comment: That's good, but my "assembly" project only contains this ssembly descriptor, so the dependencies are not being fetched (so they're not in my local dir). Also when actually fetching dependencies it always tries to fetch .jar files.

Comment: maybe, if include in project with assembly two war dependencies A and B with required versions, this A and B will be included in zip. 

Also filter can be added to "dependencySet", for include only required artifacts.